# how to send data from servelt to html page using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, servlets, struts

the scenario is the following 
i want to execute an action called by ajax and then return some data to my page 
what normaly i do is to forward this data to another jsp and  catch it and add it to my page 
as this :

```
 $.ajax({
               url: 'createPdf.do',
               data: {doc: currentTab}}).done(function(html){
               alert(html);
           }); 
 });
```

but i'm aware this not the appropriate way to do it because what really i need is the data itself not the html , so i did some research i found that   the solution is use json , but not found a good example

Comment: try success: function(data){alert(data);} instead .done()

Comment: i think you need to see this:http://viralpatel.net/blogs/creating-parsing-json-data-with-java-servlet-struts-jsp-json/

Comment: ok it's seems what i was looking for thank you